# Converting webpage to pdf with pandoc

Tags: html, pdf, pandoc

I want to convert this web page to pdf using pandoc:
        http://www.surgwiki.com/wiki/Principles_and_practice_of_cardiac_surgery

I am on Windows 10 64 bit with pandoc version 1.16.0.2.

While converting the above page I get this error:

```
pandoc: Could not find image `/w/images/thumb/Ch57-fig1.jpg/180px-Ch57-fig1.jpg', skipping...
pandoc: Could not find image `/w/skins/common/images/magnify-clip.png', skipping...
pandoc: Could not find image `/w/images/thumb/Ch57-fig2.jpg/180px-Ch57-fig2.jpg', skipping...
pandoc: Could not find image `/w/skins/common/images/magnify-clip.png', skipping...
pandoc: Could not find image `/w/skins/common/images/sharethis/BlogMarks.png', skipping...
pandoc: Could not find image `/w/skins/common/images/sharethis/del.icio.us.png', skipping...
pandoc: Could not find image `/w/skins/common/images/sharethis/digg.png', skipping...
pandoc: Could not find image `/w/skins/common/images/sharethis/Fark.png', skipping...
pandoc: Could not find image `/w/skins/common/images/sharethis/Furl.png', skipping...
pandoc: Could not find image `/w/skins/common/images/sharethis/Newsvine.png', skipping...
pandoc: Could not find image `/w/skins/common/images/sharethis/reddit.png', skipping...
pandoc: Could not find image `/w/skins/common/images/sharethis/Segnalo.png', skipping...
pandoc: Could not find image `/w/skins/common/images/sharethis/Simpy.png', skipping...
pandoc: Could not find image `/w/skins/common/images/sharethis/Slashdot.png', skipping...
pandoc: Could not find image `/w/skins/common/images/sharethis/smarking.png', skipping...
pandoc: Could not find image `/w/skins/common/images/sharethis/Spurl.png', skipping...
pandoc: Could not find image `/w/skins/common/images/sharethis/Wists.png', skipping...
pandoc: Could not find image `/w/skins/common/images/poweredby_mediawiki_88x31.png', skipping...
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `/w/images/thumb/Ch57-fig1.jpg/180px-Ch57-fig1
.jpg' not found.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.480 ...thumb/Ch57-fig1.jpg/180px-Ch57-fig1.jpg}}

pandoc: Error producing PDF
```

How to solve this problem? Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your having issues locating images that don't exist.
Here's an easy way to get around that:

- Open http://www.surgwiki.com/wiki/Principles_and_practice_of_cardiac_surgery in Google Chrome.
- Right click on the web page and click 'Save as'.
- Save that page somewhere on your computer.
- Navigate to where that page was saved on your computer and open the HTML file. A folder with the same name as the HTML should also be created, but there is no need to go into that.
- Convert the local copy of the web page (the HTML file you just opened) using pandoc.

This should fix your problem! Let me know if it works.

Comment: Is there a way to increase the font of the resulting pdf output?

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. If this resolved your problem please mark it as the answer. To increase the font size of the PDF, you can just increase the font size of the webpage text using CSS. Let me know if you need assistance with that.

Comment: Hi taylorsabell,  I want to convert this webpage http://korflab.ucdavis.edu/Unix_and_Perl/current.html using your method. But its not working. Its throwing this error:                                                                                ```                                                                                                                 ! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \@xdblarg.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.603 \subsection{

pandoc: Error producing PDF   ```

Comment: I don't have Pandoc, so I'm afraid I can't help you diagnose that error. My suggestion would be to use the PDF printing functionality that exists natively in Chrome. This article has more information: http://www.guidingtech.com/7566/chrome-print-to-pdf-convert-webpage-to-pdf/